# Android: How to fill and submit remote HTML form?

Tags: android, forms, dom, curl, input

I need to fill in and submit remote form to access JSON dataset. What is the easiest way how to fill in given form inputs and submit the form? Some cURL for Android or something similar?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: use webview or create your design that form then send data to server using Volley Lib

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncHttp` post to send post request and add parameters in `RequestParams` these params are likely to form data to submit.

Comment: Thanks, but website is sending a more params than "fomr data", there are some generated Cookies, etc.so i think that simplier should be execute form remotely..

Comment: You can call your same web form from android and send extra parameter that request is coming from mobile and apply check on server side.so you can get json in response with similer request as from web site has.